# Can I reverse a C function?

Tags: c

Basically, I want to be able to input the previously returned values and have it calculate the function's parameters. Example: given the program below, I want to input "result" and have it calculate "num1" and "num2". My function is much more complicated though.

```
int max(int num1, int num2) {

   if (num1 > num2)
      result = num1;
   else
      result = num2;

   return result; 
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: There is no generic way to reverse functions. Can you imagine the implications that would have for things like cryptography?

Comment: Compare to: *I choose 2 numbers, and I tell you that the largest is 10. Can you guess the other number*?

Comment: In general, no, what you are asking for is not possible. Think about it: given `max(1, 4)`, `max(2, 4)`, and `max(3, 4)`, if you enter `4`, should it return `1`, `2`, or `3`?  It is impossible to reverse a process like this.

Comment: 5 + 3 = 8 and 6 + 2 = 8. Can you give me back 5 and 3 uniquely if I give you 8? How would you know that I did not want 6 and 2 or 7 and 1?

Comment: If the function is invertible. The one in the question is not.

Comment: BTW there exists software like Eureqa that can reverse-engineer functions like this given some examples of inputs their outputs. But this is an NP-hard problem in the general case.

Comment: Your question really doesn't have much to do with computer languages. It is a mathematical question. In theory, only functions which have an inverse function, a.k.a. [bijective functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) can be handled this way. The alternative is to program custom functions, each with its own _undo stack_ for a given input. This would however work only within a program runtime, for _non-bijective_ functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this easily. This is why public-key cryptography works - it is easy to calculate one way but hard to find out the original parameters.

You could try all the possible permutations of num1 and num2 and search until you get the desired result, but that would take orders of magnitude longer than going forward.

Also, as mentioned or alluded to in a comment, functions are not always 1..1 in both directions. For example, there is only one answer to the question "What is the average of 10 and 20?" while there are infinite answers to the question "What two numbers average out to 15?". Obviously 10 and 20 average to 15, but 11 and 19 also average to 15.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible when each input produces a single output.

If your function was f(x) -> n, you could feed it every possible value for x, record n, and then you would have a lookup table that could be used to find x, when given n.

This is how password cracking works on poorly designed systems.

If the function requires multiple parameters that can produce the same value, there is no way to get the inputs when given the outputs, since f(x,y) -> 3 could be f(1,2) or f(-10000, 10003) or anything else.